# Camel Dynamic Mock Endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a particular route that is denoted as http://dummy in my route builder.

The reason being that at run time I dynamically generate what the actual route should be and send it as part of the header that Camel then picks up and uses instead.

This works in practice however it is problematic when using Mocks.

I am wondering - in Camel is it possible to Mock an endpoint that does not exist (at compile time) in your route builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use Camel's [AdviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) APIs to replace your dummy endpoint with a mock endpoint for testing